# CMake Deletes .dll file copied to Debug folder when I launch the target

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, cmake, vcpkg

I was trying to setup vcpkg and CMake to use with MSVC Compiler in VS Code.
I followed this guide
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/examples/installing-and-using-packages

When the first time I launched the target using CMake option "Launch" in status bar, the program ran perfectly. I tried launching the second time with a minor change and it didn't work.

After some time I figured out that Building the project for the first time works perfectly. If I go to Debug folder and I can see main.exe and sqlite3.dll file. When I execute main.exe it does what it is supposed to do.

After building the project using CMake when I click on Launch Target the .dll file gets deleted automatically so I clean and rebuild which restores the .dll file.

My question is, is there a way to stop CMake from deleting the .dll file when I press Launch from status bar in vscode?

Files in the project:

CMakeLists.txt

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test)

# Set the path to the toolchain file
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

set(unofficial-sqlite3_DIR "C:/vcpkg/packages/sqlite3_x64-windows/share/unofficial-sqlite3")

find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE unofficial::sqlite3::sqlite3)
```

main.cpp

```
// main.cpp
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << sqlite3_libversion() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello, World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably, something wrong about how do you copy the `.dll` file into the `Debug` folder. But since you don't describe that aspect, we cannot help you. You need to provide **more details** about your project.

Comment: I can share all the files? I did everything the tutorial asks me to do. The .dll file is added to Debug folder by CMake itself when I Clean > Build the project in that sequence.

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable after the `project()` is too late: You need to set that variable before the first `project()` command or as a parameter to `cmake.exe` itself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried your suggestions. The same problem persists.

Clean Rebuild restores the .dll to Debug folder.
After that, any Build or Launch or Debug command deletes .dll.

Comment: Adding `--clean-build` to build args and selecting Build before Run (both settings are in CMake tools settings in vscode) fixes the problem. This is a hack and not a solution so if anyone has better suggestions please share.

Comment: Set `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` before `project()` (don't forget to clean cache after this), remove `set(unofficial-sqlite3_DIR ...)` and bump your `cmake_minimum_required`

Comment: @Osyotr did as you suggested. moved `TOOLCHAIN_FILE` before project, but when I commented out `set(unofficial-sqlite3_DIR ...)` CMake refused to build and asked for the location again. I also bumped `cmake_min_req` as suggested. The same issue still persists.